# Srednicki's QFT: LSZ Reduction Formula for an Interacting Field Theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams

I'm reading the chapter on Scattering Amplitudes and Feynman Rules from Srednicki's *Qunatum Field Theory.* Here's an excerpt from the chapter:

[image]

I'm not sure of how $(10.6)$ has been written or derived.

> 1. I'm not sure how can one factor the Klein Gordon operators and the propagators as in the first line of $(10.6)$. I think it's just by brute force: expand and then collect the similar terms. Is there a shortcut to it?
> 2. More importantly, I don't see how the second line is derived from the first line in $(10.6)$. I tried doing a Fourier Transform, as suggested, but I couldn't complete the argument. Also, I don't get (even intuitively) how does one get,
>
> $$ \bar{k}_{ij'} = \frac{k_{i} + k'_{j}}{2}. $$

It'd be great if someone could provide the missing steps, especially for $(2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correlation function is a whole bunch of propagators joining the four points in pairs. What Srednicki writes in equation 10.6 is just one of those terms. There are others; for example, $x_1$ can be matched with $x_2$ and $x'_1$ with $x'_2$, or you can match $x_1$ with $x'_2$ and $x_2$ with $x'_1$. The structure will be almost identical.

As for the integral, it splits into two identical factors, of the form

$$\int d^4x\ d^4x'\ e^{i(kx-k'x')} F(x-x')$$

Now do a substitution

$$\begin{align}
y &= x-x' & x &= \frac12 y + z \\
z &= \frac12 (x+x') & x' &= z - \frac12 y
\end{align}$$

The integral becomes

$$\int d^4y\ d^4 z\ e^{i(k-k')z} e^{i\frac12 (k+k')y} F(y)$$

And the result follows.

Comment: Hey. Can you tell me how the change of variable is motivated? It awfully looks like a change of frame where one considers the relative co-ordinates and the center of mass of a two particle system?

Comment: @JunaidAftab: The motivation comes from noticing that $F$ is a function only of $x-x'$, so it's natural to define $y=x-x'$. $z$ is motivated like you say by the center of mass; the factor of $1/2$ makes the Jacobian simple, otherwise you'd have to deal with pesky factors of $2$.